# Accuracy of htaccess testing tools

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I trying to improve my understanding of htaccess rewrite rules and used a couple of online testing tools to verify a simple rewrite I did, but I don't understand why the returned url is repeated. I'm questioning if my rule is wrong of if there is something inherently wrong with this tool?

All I am trying to do is redirect all requests to a .com domain to the same page on a .com.au domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .? "https://domain.com.au%{REQUEST_URI}" [L,R=301]
```

So as I understand, this says:

- Conditions: If the host is `domain.com` OR `www.domain.com`
- Rule: match anything or nothing as the requested uri and redirect to `https://domain.com.au/whatever-the-request-uri-is`

But when I test this using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be for example, the returned url repeats like `https://domain.com.au/bloghttps://domain.com.au/bloghttps://domain.com.au/blog...`
However on the web server it appears to work fine.

The other rule I tried was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this returns a single correct result using the testing tool, but I read that it's preferable to use the server variables.

So is there something wrong with my first rule or is that testing tool broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works according to my tests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I am currently unable to explain why your own attempt does not, though. Sorry! I have the impression that this is indeed a bug inside the test utility, assuming that you used `https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/` ...

Comment: Thank you - I like your implementation better, it's much cleaner. So just providing `^` is just saying: match the start? 
I think I worked out what's actually happening with the duplicated output when using `.?` - it's replacing the url for each character in the request_uri so /blog is replaced 5 times.. not sure if that's how works on an actual apache server though...?

Comment: Your matching pattern `.?` somehow is an issue for that test utility. Things surprisingly work if you replace it using `.+`, surprising because both operators are greedy, `?` and `+` likewise. But that does not answer your question. And no, your pattern `.?` does not replace anything, it is only used to match, whatever it will match in the end. The replacing is only done in the next argument, the target, and that has nothing to do with the matching pattern. It appears as if `%{REQUEST_URI}` is modified in the test utility, why ever.